# Ignore duplicate date values

Tags: d3.js, crossfilter, dc.js

I have some data that has duplicate dates in it, but the values will always be the same - how do I count occurrence only once and reflect it on a bar chart?

I'm guessing I need to setup a filter function on grouping, I'm not sure how to go about this.

The data:

```
var jsonStr = ([
   {"date": "2011-11-14", "value": 0.1121},
   {"date":"2011-11-25", "value": -0.0231},
   {"date":"2011-11-25", "value": -0.0231},
   {"date":"2011-11-25", "value": -0.0231}
]);
```

The code:

```
//setup dimensions
var dateDimension = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
    return d.value;
});

var fluctuation = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
    return Math.round(d.value *10)/10;
});

var fluctuationGroup = fluctuation.group();
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wbott70/xtjJn/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This probably isn't the most efficient way to do this, but using a map is simple and short:

```
var uniqueValues = d3.map([])
jsonStr.forEach(function(d){ uniqueValues.set(d.date, d); });

newJsonStr = []
uniqueValues.forEach(function(d){ newJsonStr.push(uniqueValues.get(d)); });
```

The result:

```
[{"date":"2011-11-14","value":0.1121},{"date":"2011-11-25","value":-0.0231}]
```

Comment: Thank you Adam. Unfortunately in an effort to make the question straightforward I oversimplified the problem...there are other columnar values in there that make the rows unique. Still, I suppose I could set up a new dimension with a new set of data - I will ultimately have thousands of row to deal with...

Comment: The solution still works if you use the combination of the two properties for the key: uniqueValues.set(JSON.stringify(d.date) + JSON.stringify(d.otherField)), d). Don't worry about the thousands of rows; javascript is reasonably fast now.

Answer (score 1):

The better would probably be to remove the duplicates in the data (if you never need this information), before using the Crossfilter library, using the following code, just after your definition of `jsonStr`:

```
var newJson = [];
for (var i = 0; i < jsonStr.length; i++) {
    var found = false;
    for (var j = 0; j < newJson.length; j++) {
        if (jsonStr[i].date === newJson[j].date) {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!found) {
        newJson.push(jsonStr[i]);
    }
}
jsonStr = newJson;
```

Comment: Thank you - see my response above. I am thinking on load of the data I can fish out the duplicates into a separate array (this data will have other unique columnar values for the same date)